# How can I insert 50 rows in a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table `test_table` with attributes as `recordnumber` and `currentdate`.

How can I insert 50 rows in this table in Oracle

Comment: Using 50 INSERT statements, may be - Just saying!

Comment: How this gets upvoted?

Comment: By `attributes` you meant `columns`, I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
 insert into test_table  select rownum , sysdate  from dual connect by level <= 50  ;
```

> > Simply you can do this

Answer (score 0):

If you just want fifty rows with the same date and different record numbers this will do it for you:

```
insert into test_table
    (recordnumber , currentdate)
select rownum
       , trunc(sysdate)
from dual
connect by level <= 50
```

You can vary the date by substituting `date '2017-12-31' + level` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to get record number and row inserted time

```
create table test_table ( 
recordnumber    number(10),
currentdate timestamp 
);

insert into test_table (select level , systimestamp  from dual connect by level <= 50 ) ;

commit;

select * from test_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party on this question, but I like to use common table expressions. Here is the same answer using a CTE:

```
INSERT INTO test_table
    WITH
        aset (record_number)
        AS
            (SELECT 1 AS record_number
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT record_number + 1
               FROM aset
              WHERE record_number < 50)
    SELECT record_number, SYSTIMESTAMP
      FROM aset
```